# Problema con JQuery y textarea al cargar variable con salto de linea

Tags: php, jquery

paso a describir mi problema.
Tengo un modal el cual consta de algunos imputs y dos textarea. Es un modal de edición de datos ya inserados en la BD. Cargo los datos al modal con una funcion hecha en JQuery, todo va bien hasta que ingreso saltos de lineas en los textareas, en cualquiera de los dos, cuando es asi me carga el modal sin ningun dato.
Así tengo el código
MODAL:

```
  <div class="row">

      <input type="text" hidden="" id="idpersona" name="">
 <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Autos Caratulados</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="autosu" value="" class="form-control 
input-sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Fecha de Ingreso</label>
      <input type="date" name="" id="fechau" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>N° de Expediente</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="expedienteu" class="form-control input-
sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Nombre</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="nombreu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Apellido</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="apellidou" class="form-control input-
sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>DNI</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="dniu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>



   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
      <input type="date" name="" id="fechanu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-4"><label>Estado</label> 
<select name="test" id="estadou" class="form-control form-control-sm" >

<option value="Procesal">Procesal</option>
<option value="Adopcion">Adopción</option>
<option value="Restitucion">Restitución</option>
<option value="Flia Solidaria">Flia Solidaria</option>
</select></div>



</select>

  <div class="col-sm-12"><hr /></div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Nombre y Apellido Progenitora</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="nmadreu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>


   <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Teléfono</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="telmadreu" class="form-control input-
 sm">
  </div>


  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Nombre y Apellido Pogenitor</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="npadreu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
      <label>Teléfono</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="telu" class="form-control input-sm">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Domicilio</label>
      <input type="text" name="" id="domiciliou" class="form-control input-
 sm">
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-12"><hr/></div>


<div class="col-sm-6">
<label>Familia Extensa</label>
<textarea class="form-control"  rows="10"   id="familiaextensau"></textarea>
</div>

 <div class="col-sm-6">
<label>Observaciones</label>
<textarea class="form-control"   rows="10"  id="observacionesu"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Así paso los datos de la consulta a la funcion agregaform JQuery desde PHP:

```
            $sql="SELECT id,autos,fecha,expediente,nombre,
             apellido,dni,fechan,estado,nmadre,telmadre,
             npadre,tel,domicilio,familiaextensa,observaciones
                    from t_persona order by fecha asc";
            }
           $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){ 

                $datos=$ver[0]."||".

                       $ver[1]."||".
                       $ver[2]."||".
                       $ver[3]."||".
                       $ver[4]."||".
                       $ver[5]."||".
                       $ver[6]."||".
                       $ver[7]."||".
                       $ver[8]."||".
                       $ver[9]."||".
                       $ver[10]."||".
                       $ver[11]."||".
                       $ver[12]."||".
                       $ver[13]."||".
                        $ver[14]."||".
                          $ver[15]."||"



                       ;

         ?>


            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">

                </button>
```

y esta es la función JQuery:

```
  function agregaform(datos){

d=datos.split('||');

$('#idpersona').val(d[0]);
$('#autosu').val(d[1]);
$('#fechau').val(d[2]);
$('#expedienteu').val(d[3]);
$('#nombreu').val(d[4]);
$('#apellidou').val(d[5]);
$('#dniu').val(d[6]);
$('#fechanu').val(d[7]);
$('#estadou').val(d[8]);
$('#nmadreu').val(d[9]);
$('#telmadreu').val(d[10]);
$('#npadreu').val(d[11]);
$('#telu').val(d[12]);
$('#domiciliou').val(d[13]);

$('#familiaextensau').val(d[14]);
$('#observacionesu').val(d[15]);


 }
```

No puedo encontrar el error, leí en la documentacion de .val que es usado para imputs, selects y textarea indistintamente y tendría que funcionar, pero el problema es con los saltos de linea que ingreso en el mismo. 
Que piensan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpen, ya solucione el problema, con preg_replace  remplace (desde PHP) los caracteres no imprimibles por "\n" en el string entregado a jquery. Lo hice de esta manera:

```
 preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '\n', $datos)
```

Comment: Gracias por compartir la solución, Santiago. Te recuerdo que luego del período de tiempo (48h) puedes marcar tu propia respuesta como correcta.